# SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync generate many database access

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, sql-server-profiler

In my application, I use ASP.NET Identity. Every thing is work fine but by testing, I found that the following command produces many database accesses:
SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
```

I notice this problem when testing the application using performance test. The test shows that the login request needs huge time to get response. The following figure shows result of performance test for the login request:
[image].

Then I use SQL Server Profiler to check what happen when the command SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync is executed. It shows that a lot of database accesses is generated. The following is taken from SQL Server Profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[UserFullName] AS [UserFullName], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[Online] AS [Online], 
    [Extent1].[LastOnlineDate] AS [LastOnlineDate], 
    [Extent1].[BrithDate] AS [BrithDate], 
    [Extent1].[Job] AS [Job], 
    [Extent1].[Gender] AS [Gender], 
    [Extent1].[CountryId] AS [CountryId], 
    [Extent1].[LivesIn] AS [LivesIn], 
    [Extent1].[RelationId] AS [RelationId], 
    [Extent1].[Religion] AS [Religion], 
    [Extent1].[FirstSchool] AS [FirstSchool], 
    [Extent1].[SecondSchool] AS [SecondSchool], 
    [Extent1].[University] AS [University], 
    [Extent1].[ContactInfo] AS [ContactInfo], 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Extent1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
    [Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
    [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ((UPPER([Extent1].[UserName])) = (UPPER(@p__linq__0))) OR ((UPPER([Extent1].[UserName]) IS NULL) AND (UPPER(@p__linq__0) IS NULL))',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'User1@gmail.com'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[ClaimType] AS [ClaimType], 
    [Extent1].[ClaimValue] AS [ClaimValue]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=2103

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[ClaimType] AS [ClaimType], 
    [Extent1].[ClaimValue] AS [ClaimValue]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=2103

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[LoginProvider] AS [LoginProvider], 
    [Extent1].[ProviderKey] AS [ProviderKey], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=2103
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=2103
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[UserFullName] AS [UserFullName], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[Online] AS [Online], 
    [Extent1].[LastOnlineDate] AS [LastOnlineDate], 
    [Extent1].[BrithDate] AS [BrithDate], 
    [Extent1].[Job] AS [Job], 
    [Extent1].[Gender] AS [Gender], 
    [Extent1].[CountryId] AS [CountryId], 
    [Extent1].[LivesIn] AS [LivesIn], 
    [Extent1].[RelationId] AS [RelationId], 
    [Extent1].[Religion] AS [Religion], 
    [Extent1].[FirstSchool] AS [FirstSchool], 
    [Extent1].[SecondSchool] AS [SecondSchool], 
    [Extent1].[University] AS [University], 
    [Extent1].[ContactInfo] AS [ContactInfo], 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Extent1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
    [Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
    [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=2103
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[ClaimType] AS [ClaimType], 
    [Extent1].[ClaimValue] AS [ClaimValue]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=2103
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[LoginProvider] AS [LoginProvider], 
    [Extent1].[ProviderKey] AS [ProviderKey], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=2103

    exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
        [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Extent1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId]
        FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=2103
    exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[UserFullName] AS [UserFullName], 
        [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Extent1].[Online] AS [Online], 
        [Extent1].[LastOnlineDate] AS [LastOnlineDate], 
        [Extent1].[BrithDate] AS [BrithDate], 
        [Extent1].[Job] AS [Job], 
        [Extent1].[Gender] AS [Gender], 
        [Extent1].[CountryId] AS [CountryId], 
        [Extent1].[LivesIn] AS [LivesIn], 
        [Extent1].[RelationId] AS [RelationId], 
        [Extent1].[Religion] AS [Religion], 
        [Extent1].[FirstSchool] AS [FirstSchool], 
        [Extent1].[SecondSchool] AS [SecondSchool], 
        [Extent1].[University] AS [University], 
        [Extent1].[ContactInfo] AS [ContactInfo], 
        [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
        [Extent1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
        [Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
        [Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
        [Extent1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
        [Extent1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
        [Extent1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
        [Extent1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
        [Extent1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
        [Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
        [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
        FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=2103
    exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Extent1].[ClaimType] AS [ClaimType], 
        [Extent1].[ClaimValue] AS [ClaimValue]
        FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=2103
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[LoginProvider] AS [LoginProvider], 
    [Extent1].[ProviderKey] AS [ProviderKey], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=2103
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=2103
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[UserFullName] AS [UserFullName], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[Online] AS [Online], 
    [Extent1].[LastOnlineDate] AS [LastOnlineDate], 
    [Extent1].[BrithDate] AS [BrithDate], 
    [Extent1].[Job] AS [Job], 
    [Extent1].[Gender] AS [Gender], 
    [Extent1].[CountryId] AS [CountryId], 
    [Extent1].[LivesIn] AS [LivesIn], 
    [Extent1].[RelationId] AS [RelationId], 
    [Extent1].[Religion] AS [Religion], 
    [Extent1].[FirstSchool] AS [FirstSchool], 
    [Extent1].[SecondSchool] AS [SecondSchool], 
    [Extent1].[University] AS [University], 
    [Extent1].[ContactInfo] AS [ContactInfo], 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Extent1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
    [Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
    [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=2103
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[ClaimType] AS [ClaimType], 
    [Extent1].[ClaimValue] AS [ClaimValue]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=2103
```

The above queries are just a part of the result. The same queries are executed several times. Is this the normal case or there is a problem ?

If it is a problem, how it can be solved.

Comment: Queries are really fast, but in my case I have so many of them (mostly the same query repeated once and again) that it provokes a delay of 1 second per page request

Comment: can you show us more of your c# code? I cannot understand how your command is used. Maybe you have a Thread running repeatedly but still I need more info

Comment: I agree with jambonick you should write some code more.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're using the Identity setup 'as it comes'. In which case you will also probably be using Entity Framework.

To answer your question: In my experience, the UserStore that sits behind `UserManager`, `SignInManager` etc is accessed multiple times when an action is carried out.

The main problem I noticed was they this was incredibly slow with EntityFramework in place. I found that if I created my own CustomUserStore it dramatically sped up the login/user action speed. There are **still multiple calls** to the methods but performs far better.

In my case I used the Micro-ORM `Dapper.NET` to drive my new UserStore. Dapper can perform queries much faster than EntityFramework (3-10 times faster depending on the query in some tests - see: https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/dapper-vs-entity-framework-vs-ado-net-performance-benchmarking/)

Dapper.NET: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

With the custom UserStore rewrite, you can find *loads* of examples online but here is one: https://markjohnson.io/articles/exorcising-entity-framework-from-asp-net-identity/

Comment: Not going to downvote, but saying "my own CustomUserStore" without showing why it is much faster than provided EF store is a non-answer. Also "faster" is such inaccurate term. How much faster and why?